# how often lock screen data can be updated in windows phone using lock screen app in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I heard this new and exciting feature in Windows Phone 7.8  and 8 where we can write lock screen app.how often lock screen data can be updated in using lock screen app in windows phone 8?

Answer (score -1):

The lock screen data is taken directly from the primary tile (and you can also set the background), so I think the question may really be how often can the tile be updated?

For the tile to be updated while the lock screen is shown, you'd likely be using a [periodic background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and those run every 30 minutes for 25 seconds.

Alternatively, the tile updates could be driven by push notifications. There is a [limit of 500 per day if sent in unauthenticated mode, but unlimited if authenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx#ID4EHD1).